# Foreign key constraint phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have set up relations in a database and am having problems with my foreign and primary keys. I am trying to use auto-increment on one of a primary key in one table, however when I go to save the changes the message appears 'Query error: #1833 - Cannot change column 'Student_ID': used in a foreign key constraint 'competitor_ibfk_1' of table 'sportsday.competitor'

Any solutions to fix the foreign key problem thanks

Using phpmyadmin and XAMPP.

Comment: Remove the foreign key constraint in the other table, add the auto-inc, then re-add the foreign key constraint http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: @A.O. thanks will try now, cant seem to find where to delete the constraint, would it be the whole field? and then just re-add it

Comment: No, you do not need to drop the whole column, it's in the link in my first comment, something like `ALTER TABLE table_name DROP FOREIGN KEY...`